# empty value of element in IE

Tags: php, javascript, html

This code in firefox is working. In IE the alert is empty.

```
<select id="ronny"  name="ronny" onchange="AjaxPost();alert(document.getElementById('ronny').value);">
   <option id="selected_ronny">All</option>
     <?php
      foreach($d_ronny as $ronny)
        {
          if ($ronny == $_POST['ronny_select'])
            {
              echo "<option selected id='selected_ronny'>$ronny</option>";
            }
          else
            {
              echo "<option>$ronny</option>";
            }
        }
     ?>
</select>
```

The options are fox example :
`All`
`abc`
`123`
`xyz`
When i select `xyz`, the alert shows `xyz`. In IE the alert is empty.

thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code for AjaxPost()?

Comment: the post is fine. the problem is the value of the select.

Comment: If you remove the call to `AjaxPost();` you might find it works, so we need to see why that breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the onchange attribute you have to code like this :

```
onchange="AjaxPost();alert(this.options[selectedIndex].value);"
```

If you want to use the id, replace `thi`s by `document.getElementById('ronny')` :

```
onchange="AjaxPost();alert(document.getElementById('ronny').options[selectedIndex].value);"
```

Comment: thank you! but i have a problem..i want to use the selected index later in other JS and i have some. so how can i make it with id?

Comment: thank you! but i have an error in ie and ff - `'selectedIndex' is undefined`

Comment: It works for me, but Try : `alert(document.getElementById('ronny').options[document.getElementById('ronny').selectedIndex].value);`