# empty value of option's element

Tags: javascript

I have a similar problem like old [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745179/empty-value-of-element-in-ie/) of mine.

my code:

```
function reset_admin()
{
    a = document.getElementById('event').value;
    t = document.getElementById('category').value;
    document.getElementById('admin').reset();
    document.getElementById('event').value = a;
    document.getElementById('category').value = t;
}
<form id="admin" action="iframe_admin.php" onsubmit="" method="post" target="iframe_admin">
.....
<input type="button" class="filter_button" id="Clear" name="Clear" value="Clear" 
onclick="reset_admin();document.getElementById('admin').submit(); />
```

the function is in external js file.
the propose is that after pressing on clear, the event and the category will stay the same before the clear.

In ff it's works. In IE the event and the category are empty and than the page get stacked.
I tried to do:

```
function reset_admin()
{
    a = document.getElementById('event').options[getElementById('event').selectedIndex].value;
    t = document.getElementById('category').options[getElementById('category').selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('admin').reset();
    document.getElementById('event').value = a;
    document.getElementById('category').value = t;
}
```

but this is not working as well.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store and restore the [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement) instead since you don't care about the *actual* value, like this:

```
function reset_admin()
{
    var a = document.getElementById('event').selectedIndex,
        t = document.getElementById('category').selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById('admin').reset();
    document.getElementById('event').selectedIndex = a;
    document.getElementById('category').selectedIndex = t;
}
```

I also added `var` to the indexes your fetching, just to about the global variables there, but that's not the important change, setting `selectedIndex` instead is :)

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qTaTB/).